# std140 and bool alignment

Tags: opengl, shader

According to OpenGL specs 4.5, `bool` in std140 layout block reserve 1 byte (`sizeof(GLboolean) == 1`).
But when I get the offset of `b`, it is 4.
Where is the misunderstanding?

```
layout (std140) uniform Uniforms
{
    bool a;
    bool b;
};
```

The following structure expands 4 bytes to 64. Why engineers created a so super resource-wasted standard?

```
layout (std140) uniform Uniforms
{
    bool a[4];
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GLboolean` is an altogether different type from `bool` in GLSL.

The smallest scalar data type in GLSL is 32-bit, so everything is aligned to some multiple of 4-bytes. For anything smaller than 32-bit you generally want to pack and unpack an integer or floating-point value yourself, so I would consider using a `uint` instead.

You can store 32 `bool` values in one `uint` if you do the packing yourself.